# Background-image on just the homepage

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, background-image

I want to build an application that on its homepage contains a `background-image`. The issue I am having is that the only content on the home will come from a `layouts/header` partial and as soon as you go to `another controller's views`, the `background image` should not be there.

I realised that if I type `body{ background-image: url('background.jpg') }` it will work but it will also be there for every other page.

The other problem is that the code below works, only if the content of the page is big enough to cover the `image's size`.

**app/views/store/home**

```
<div class = "home">

</div>
```

**css**

```
.home {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
}
```

So, the `background image` doesn't appear on the background. What `css` rule should I apply to get that working?

Comment: Use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `<body>` `id` attribute that you can dynamically pass the value of the current controller and action to:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body id="<%= params[:controller]+'_'+params[:action] %>">
```

So assuming that your `<body>` `id` is `home_index`, you can target the following in CSS:

```
body#home_index {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url('background.png');
}
```

This way, only the `<body>` tag on the homepage (presumably the one rendered from the `index` action of the `home` controller, in this example) has the CSS style applied to it.

Comment: I just fixed your answer into something that half-works. So now, on inspecting the page the body tag is `body id = "home_index"` but for some reason it doesn't pick up the image.

Comment: Assuming you're on Rails >3.1, you'll be able to tap into the image through the asset pipeline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Try the amended path in my answer.

Comment: I fixed it based on your answer. The correct should be <body id="`<%= params[:controller]+'-'+params[:action] %>">`.

Comment: Whether the `id` uses an underscore or a hyphen shouldn't matter, so long as the CSS selector is named accordingly. Be sure that there's no spaces between the `id` name and the value, i.e., `id="home_index"`.

Comment: I think CSS convention is to user hyphen rather than underscore so that's why I used it.

Comment: That's actually just preference. Many use hyphens, but many use underscores because most text editors and IDEs allow you to select the entire string with a double-click of the mouse. Did it work to remove the spaces on either side of the equals sign?

Comment: why are you not accepting the edit? the code above produces literally the following html: `<body id="#{params[:controller]+'_'+params[:action]}">`. Two things wrong with the above. One there shouldn't be a `#` after the equals sign. You already selected `body` to be an `id`. Second, by not having `<%= =>` you are literally printing it to the screen instead instead interpolating the values.

Comment: Very right... it's been a long night. Updated to reflect. Does it work now?

Comment: Another small change, you don't really need the `/assests/` in the url.